# How to make Chrome render these characters correctly?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts, unicode

I ran into this font weirdness today (in Chrome, on 18.04):

[image]

It should look like this (Screenshot from Firefox on the same system):

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

1. Installing a bunch of font extensions in Chrome that accomplish
   nothing
2. Manually setting Chrome's fonts under Settings --> Appearance to match Firefox's use of system fonts

Comment: If you share a link, others can check it out on their browsers.

Comment: Sure! Here it is https://courses.prts.edu/pause/

Comment: Hmm… It displays properly for me in Google Chrome Version 73.0.3683.75 (Official Build) (64-bit) without having to change anything. Can you try with a new user? Click on your user icon to the left of the ☰ icon and then on *Manage people* and then on *Add person*.

Comment: Interesting. I'm away from my laptop right now but will investigate further when I get home.

Comment: I'm on the same version.  Bizarre. I got home and reloaded the page, and it loaded correctly.